# How do I send automatic pdf mails taking values from DB

Tags: laravel

Hello guys I need help here,

I want to send PDF mails to users on a monthly basics. but the PDF will have values from the db. so each users has a different content from another user all taking values from db. If i can't achieve this perfectly on Laravel I need another language that can help me achieve this thanks.

```
$schedule->command('custom:command')
         ->monthly();
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve anything in Laravel which you can achieve in PHP :) and as far as web development is concerned, you can achieve anything in PHP :)

However, I am not sure what exactly is your question about so I will answer all aspects of sending an email with dynamic pdf.

#### Get fillable PDF

First of all, you need fillable fields in your pdf in order to generate a dynamic pdf in run time. If you dont have fillable fields in your pdf, you can create them using any online tool. One example is: https://www.pdfescape.com/

You can also use Adobe to do so if you like.

#### Create a PDF with dynamic data

Once you have your empty, fillable PDF, then you can populate the data in it using [PDFTK](https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/) library. Of course, you will have to install this tool in your Server in order to use it.

I recommend using it directly, running `exec` or similar commands in PHP. However, if you are not comfortable, you can use various Pdftk wrapper, available in Laravel. One example is: https://github.com/mikehaertl/php-pdftk

I myself prefer using `exec` directly from PHP. Here is a REALLY GOOD tutorial for that: https://www.sitepoint.com/filling-pdf-forms-pdftk-php/

#### Send the email

Well once you have your PDF generated and saved on Server, all you need to do is attach it with your email and send. You can find all about attachments in Laravel here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/mail#attachments

#### Run it via cron

If you have to do it on a regular basis. I advise you create a cron on your Server. There are various ways to do that. I advise you do it via cPanel, if you have one on your server of course as it provides very user-friendly way of creating crons. If not, you can also use terminal to edit the cron files in Linux Server.

I do not recommend using Laravel inbuild scheduler because it has known issues.

Well that's it, voila..that's the whole process of sending dynamically generated PDFs via email on regular basis.
Good luck!